# Automatic updates are not auto-downloading

Tags: xbox-one

I have my Xbox One set up to automatically download and install updates, the rest of my settings are shown below:

[image: settings]

Is there a reason my games will show an update symbol on their tile, **but they still don't download the update until I start the game manually?**

Comment: I think auto updates only work when the Xbox is set to "energy saving mode" (i.e. always on, but using low power when not in use), but I'm not positive on that.

Comment: thanks, i will compare with a friends setup who has working auto downloads. ill give that a shot on mine as well and update here if it works.

Comment: @Adeese sorry, just got home to check and when you switch to energy-saving mode, it tells you to switch back to instant-on mode if you want auto updates, so it's the other way around. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Maybe I used the wrong name. What I meant was if you have the Xbox in the mode where it doesn't turn off, but starts up quickly, that is when auto updates work (which, based on your screenshot, your Xbox isn't set to).

Comment: @Adeese My power mode is instant on. That's what you're talking about, where it doesnt shut down (shutting down would be energy saving mode, since being off saves energy). And mine is set to instant on, based on my screenshot. Take a look at your settings, if you have an xbox one, and compare to mine.

Comment: Oh, my bad - I saw "turn Xbox off" and thought that meant it was fully powering off. Sorry about that.

Comment: No problem, doesn't look like anyone else is even curious about it, maybe I'll try resetting to defaults

Comment: Hopefully that will help. If not, you could try contacting @XboxSupport on Twitter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a line in the xbox support docs that is, at least for me, inaccurate. It says the xbox will check for updates in the "off" state (instant-on low power state), which happens every time I shut the xbox down at night. However, that's not working.

[image: auto download rules]

What I figured out after reading this, and some trial and error, was that I have my Xbox set to "never turn off automatically", and for some reason, this turns off the auto downloading. Despite the fact that the docs say it should work regardless of that particular setting's value, as long as you turn your console off once in a while (which I do), I wasn't seeing downloads come through.

But, after switching my console to turn off after 6 hours of inactivity, uninstalling an update, and turning the console off manually, I am now seeing the update download automatically in the "off" state, as well as in the background after starting the console.

Comment: Can you confirm this isn't for the console's updates only but for games too?

Comment: Yep, I tested by uninstalling an update for diablo ros and as soon as I powered down, the update started downloading. I ha e a friend who gets home from work and his games are updated, while I get home and have to trigger it manually and wait for it to work. Otherwise I wouldn't have known it was possible. His setup and mine only differed by our tinwout value, mine was never, his was 1 hour. Now mine is working using 6 hr timeout.

Comment: The xbox doc also says *games and apps*

Answer (score 0):

You have to switch it where it says "don't turn off automatically" to "1" or "6 hours of inactivity", when the Xbox turns off or you turn it off, then and only then will it update

Answer (score 0):

If you have your games on external HDD go to *Settings* and then *Power mode & startup*, you should have the box "*When Xbox is off, turn off storage*" unchecked. This should solve it.