# Does the Xbox One automatically download app/game updates?

Tags: xbox-one

My console is set to use the Instant-On power mode and I’ve checked the box allowing it to “download updates automatically” when in this mode.

However, when I launch games and apps, I still see the “Oh, shoot. We need to update first” screen quite often. I’ve also noticed that items in my download queue are not completed while in Instant-On mode.

Is this setting really just for system updates? Or does it apply to app/game updates as well? Is it available outside the United States or something silly?

Edit: My console does go to sleep so that is not the issue.

Comment: Do you have the energy saver mode turned on or the quick start mode turned on? When I set up my new system last night it implied automatic updates were only guaranteed to be smooth if you were on the Quick Start mode (which means its always on).

Comment: I asked a similar question [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/233585/108888), and found a solution that works for me. We may not have the same issue though, I never had problems with my download queue.

Comment: this seems to be the exact problem you were having, and the solutions appear to be the same, too.

Comment: That is not it. My console does go to sleep, it just doesn’t update any games or apps while in that state.

Answer (score 1):

I've never ran into this issue with my Xbox One. I have noticed occasionally that an update will show as being finished when I first boot up my One. I have left mine in Instant On mode since I bought it.

[Xbox Support: Power Modes](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-one/system/learn-about-power-modes)