# Installing Xbox One games into hard disk while in sleep mode

Tags: xbox-one

The Xbox One is capable of installing games when in sleep mode into its internal storage. However, is it able to do so with external ones as well? Do I have to keep the console on the whole time to install into an external hard disk?

Comment: To clarify, do you mean when the console is in sleep mode or completely off?

Comment: @twobugs in sleep mode, I'll add that to the question thank you

Comment: Slightly related, if you still don't see it working for updates (as opposed to fresh installs): http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/233585/108888

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your Xbox One can install both digital and physical copies of games while in Sleep mode. I have done this myself enough times to verify it, but here is [an additional source](https://www.reddit.com/r/xboxone/comments/2f9q1q/quick_question_does_it_install_disc_games_in/).

Likewise, the console is able to install either to internal storage or external drives while in sleep mode. It will attempt the install to the drive with most free space.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible to do it just make sure you have the right power option
The power option is in System < Power and startup
If you haven't do the startup Instant-on.. That's preferred for me and you will find while Xbox is off, Turn off storage, un-check it
Now you can download while Xbox is on sleep..

Comment: What's "the right power option"? Can you expand on this meager answer?

Comment: Ok just give me  a minute to tell you