# Xbox One S not automatically updating

Tags: xbox-one

My Xbox One S is part of the preview build/early update ring, but I don't remember seeing this preventing automatic updates. This goes for both system updates and game updates.

My console is set to Instant-On, I have the box checked to keep games & apps up-to-date, and my console is set to turn off after 6 hours of inactivity; I usually power off using the controller when I'm done though.

Any possible causes or would the preview updates necessarily explain everything?

Comment: Does it update when you manually go to update it?

Comment: Yep. Also, If i wait a few days between playing, I'll get the "Time to update" when I turn on the console. It will begin downloading and then the install proceeds from there

Comment: Sorry, I don't have an Xbox One, but is what you just described not it automatically updating?

Comment: No problem. Nope, the intended function is that it updates while in 'low-power mode' so you don't have to sit and wait for the download everytime you try to play something.

Comment: Possible dupe of [my question over here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/233585/108888). I solved my issue at the time, but i still randomly get games that wont auto update, while some do. Very hard to pin down a pattern.

Comment: FTR i am part of preview program (called xbox insiders now i think?), but i have a buddy who is not part of preview and he has same issue with game updates and system updates.

Comment: @Dpeif Mine's more of "no games auto update at all" situation, which includes the system itself. Do you notice any difference between XB1 and XB360 games auto updating?

Comment: @GlenDespaux not sure, i dont have any 360 games that i can remember needing an update. The behavior is so erratic, i had a Fortnite patch autodownload earlier this week, but not a 2nd patch yesterday. Smite never auto updates, ever,   neither does ARK, but Elite Dangerous does *most* of the time, and Astroneer works *every* time. Such a simple console feature, but I do not understand why it works so sporadically.

Comment: @Dpeif That's my main gripe here: just make it update! Lol they're happy enough making my computer uncontrollably update at all hours of the day, but can't keep the Xbox updates steady.